# Image classification, constant validation_accuracy and accuracy

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to classify image data using Convolutional Neural Network. Why are the loss, the accuracy and the validation_accuracy staying almost constant during the training? Can you help me with that ?

Here is some information about the structure of my image classification problem and what I've already tried.

- 4 classes from 0 to 3.
- Train set : 4400 images of size 50*50. Perfectly balanced and normalized.
- Validation set : 400 images of size 50*50. Perfectly balanced and normalized.
- Trying different models : here is simplest one.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(height, width, num_channel)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'softmax'))
```

- Trying different optimizers : for example SGD with learning rate from 0.1 to 1e-6.
- Loss : categorical crossentropy.
- Metrics : accuracy.
- Trying different batch size : 8, 16, 32...
- Results obtained with the first epochs :

[image]

- Predictions over a test set of 1715 images :

Class 0 : 1425 ; 
Class 1 : 0 ; 
Class 2 : 0 ; 
Class 3 : 290 ;

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared data to try before suggesting a model, try to use the dense layers -

---

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(height, width, num_channel)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.6),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])
```

---

If the model is overfitting the data try to reduce the dense layers.